# How to hang a dryer vent in a basement ceiling?

Tags: vent, dryer

I have an old house and had to rerun the dryer vent line from the first floor through the basement and then to the outside of the house.  I basically replaced everything the previous owner did with few exceptions.  I used the 4" semi rigid aluminum vent hose and replaced the external vent hood.  The old installation did not have cutouts in the floor joists for the vent line due to the presence of water, gas and electric lines in the path.  What can I use as a hanger to help support the 4 inch line as an alternative to cutting the joists?

Comment: A dryer vent pipe isn't heavy. I'd just go with wire.

Comment: What is "*4" semi rigid aluminum vent hose*"? That sounds like the wrong stuff. Vents are supposed to be constructed of rigid duct with a smooth walled interior, see [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/26425/33) for more detail. You can only use the flexible "transition duct" for a maximum of 8' from the dryer to the rigid duct.

Comment: This is what I used and the entire length from dryer to exterior is less than 8 ft.

http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-8-ft-Semi-Rigid-Dryer-Duct-WX08X10075DS/202214660

Comment: The transition duct also cannot be "*concealed within construction*", so passing through a floor may or may not be allowed.

Comment: For the transition through the wall I did not use the flex duct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use metal pipe hanging tape to hold it up. It comes in a roll and has several holes in it which you would use to attach it to your framing with nails or screws. Simply cut it to length with a pair of aviation snips, and nail or screw it up.

Once thing you want to be careful of is not to put it on too tight and crush the vent line.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any code restrictions, but I would opt for a heavy duty nylon zip-tie with a mounting head (the kind you can run a screw through)

Comment: I don't have metal snips, do you think the plastic stuff would work?

https://www.menards.com/main/plumbing/rough-plumbing/pipe-tubing-hoses-fittings-accessories/pipe-supports/pipe-straps/3-4-x-25-plastic-hanger-strap/p-1340657-c-19446.htm?tid=-7589678385409303682

Comment: @SteveSalowitz the plastic stuff should work fine. You probably should use a washer so the screw head doesn't pull out easily. You can use the metal stuff without snips as well. You can use pliers or a bench vise and bend it back and forth until it snaps. Then you can use a hammer to flatten it out.

Comment: That plastic strapping is designed to support drain-waste-vent (DWV) pipe.  [This document (PDF)](http://www.siouxchief.com/docs/default-source/technical-documents/other/support/plastic-hanger-strap---technical-bulletin) rates it up to 120° F, which may not be high enough for a dryer vent.

Comment: @Tester101 that is a good point, I was not aware that the rating was so low on the plastic stuff.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk I checked online and there are zip ties that are extremely heat resistant on the market. One kind can sustain up to 500f which far exceeds anything that the dryer vent will put out. There are also screw on zip tie mounts that would allow you to use any style of zip tie. As far as code goes, I have no idea, but it sounds reasonable. The zip ties would also have to be pretty long, probably 15" or so.